# is there an equivalent for SQL group by rollup in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The gist of GROUP BY ROLLUP is that if you group by multiple columns you will also see aggregates as if grouped by subsets of these columns.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by-rollup.html

is there a function in Access that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You can, however, use multiple queries and `UNION ALL` if you want totals/subtotals.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way of doing this.  Suppose you have the following:

rowID   PaymentDate PaymentDesc Amount

1           30/04/2023  April Fees  £1,500.00
2           31/05/2023  May Fees    £1,600.00
3           30/06/2023  June Fees   £1,700.00
4           31/07/2023  July Fees   £1,800.00
5           31/08/2023  August Fees £1,900.00

The SQL command below will get you the rollup:

```
SELECT tempRollUp.rowID, tempRollUp.PaymentDate, tempRollUp.PaymentDesc, tempRollUp.Amount, 
DSum("Amount","tempRollUp","PaymentDate <= #" & [PaymentDate] & "#") AS Rollup
FROM tempRollUp
ORDER BY tempRollUp.PaymentDate;
```

The trick is to sum up all the amounts where the payment date is equal to or earlier than the date of the current payment.  This is what DSum("Amount","tempRollUp","PaymentDate <= #" & [PaymentDate] & "#") does.

There is a slight caveat here, dates in DSum and similar MS Access functions are tricky - there's a bug:  #02/01/2024# will be considered to be 2024-02-01 even if you've switched all your date settings to European.

The SQL command below gives a workaround:

```
SELECT tempRollUp.rowID, tempRollUp.PaymentDate, tempRollUp.PaymentDesc, tempRollUp.Amount, 
DSum("Amount","tempRollUp","format(PaymentDate,0) <= " & format([PaymentDate],0)) AS Rollup
FROM tempRollUp
ORDER BY tempRollUp.PaymentDate;
```

This works with dates but you might not be working with dates.  Any sorted field will do.  The following SQL Command produces the same output as the above.

```
SELECT tempRollUp.rowID, tempRollUp.PaymentDate, tempRollUp.PaymentDesc, tempRollUp.Amount, DSum("Amount","tempRollUp","rowID <= " & [rowID]) AS Rollup
FROM tempRollUp
ORDER BY tempRollUp.rowID;
```

The general rule is that you'll want a formula on the pattern DSum("Amount","QueryName","sortedField <= " & [sortedField])

Comment: downvote because of: 1) OP (user: user18398254) is gone, so why waste time on a an answer which is a repetition of the already provided answer. 2) answer is not formatted properly